# How do I update one of the variables in an existing doubly linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, multiplayer

I have a pelmanism game to code. The game has this feature of multiplayer that tracks the score of the players as well. However, I need help to figure out **how to update one of the existing variables in an existing doubly linked list**, calling from a different class.

Here are some things I have tried :

- Used a search algorithm to search for a specific `index` of the node, and then call the `updateNode` to update `temp->score=(temp->score)+2`, but I could not access the existing doubly linked list created in `addNode(int index, string n, int score)` from inside of `memoryGame` (the caller). It returns an empty list when I call `display()`. I created the nodes from the `main` function and call the `addNode` function outside of the classes.

Some information about the game :

- The `memoryGame` class handles the execution of the game
- The `ADTqueue` handles the initialization of the nodes
- The rest of the functions which are not in the classes are to handle the nodes (`add`, `sort` and `display` purposes)
- The doubly linked list was created in the `addNode` function (outside of all the classes)
- The game takes in the input from user : `level` of difficulty of the game and `qty` number of players playing

Here is the main code, including the class where the game takes place, and another class to manage the doubly linked list.
https://github.com/addinaamiruddin/Multiplayer-Card-Game-with-Player-Details/blob/main/MAIN-GAME.cpp

I would love to hear suggestions on how to handle this problem. Thanks in advance to those who decided to help with my inquiry, I really appreciate this.

Comment: There are no fewer than [a dozen warnings in the posted code](https://godbolt.org/z/Ef9e6r1jo), some of them critical. Perhaps addressing those first would be a good move.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the head and the index, just search through your linked list for that particular node. If double linked list isn't a requirement then i suggest to use `std::vector` instead.

```
node* getNodeByIndex(int index){
    node *current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while(current != nullptr){
       if(count == index){
           return current; // returns searched node.
       }
       count ++;
       current = current->next;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```